# Deleting a row in ng-grid in angularjs, it also deletes the file in the next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ng-grid

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngGrid']);

app.controller('merchantController',function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.people = [
    {"name":"sd","place":"hyd"},
    {"name":"sd","place":"hyd"},    
    {"name":"sd","place":"hyd"}
  ];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data:'people',
    columnDefs:[
      {field:'name', cellTemplate:'<input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.name"/>'},
      {field:'place',cellTemplate:'<input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.place"/>'},
      {displayName:'Browse',cellTemplate:'<input type="file" name="img{{row.rowIndex}}" ng-model="row.entity.filename"/>'},      
      {displayName:"Remove",cellTemplate:'<button ng-click="remove(row.rowIndex)">Remove</button>'}
    ]
  };

  $scope.remove = function(ind) {
    var index = this.row.rowIndex;
    $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
    var form=document.forms.namedItem("gridform");
    form.elements["img"+index].value="";
    $scope.people.splice(index,1);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <link data-require="ng-grid@2.0.14" data-semver="2.0.14" rel="stylesheet"   href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/ng-grid.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.7" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-grid@2.0.14" data-semver="2.0.14" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/build/ng-grid.js">    </script>
    <script data-require="ng-grid@2.0.14" data-semver="2.0.14" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/plugins/ng-grid-flexible-height.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="merchantController">
    <form name="gridform">
      <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to remove the corresponding row, when the remove button is clicked.The row is being deleted but the file in the next row is also getting deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine with your code, but it is the problem with browser, because of browser do not change correct `files` attributes of `input[type="file"]`. You have to declare directive to watch when file is attached to input and change it is text field by yourself. For example(working code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
<link data-require="ng-grid@2.0.14" data-semver="2.0.14" rel="stylesheet"   href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/ng-grid.css" />
<script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.7" data-require="angular.js@*"></script>
<script data-require="ng-grid@2.0.14" data-semver="2.0.14" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/v2.0.14/build/ng-grid.js">    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            height: 500px;
        }
        form {
            height: 500px;
        }
        .gridStyle {
            height: 500px;
        }
        input[type='file'] {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        input[type='file']:after {
            content: attr(filename);
            margin: 0 0 0 5px;
            color: #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="merchantController">
   <form name="gridform">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
   </form>
 <script>
   var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngGrid']);
   app.directive('fileUpload', function () {
       return {
           link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
               elem.on('change', function () {
                   var filename = this.files[0].name;
                   var index = attrs.index;
                   var row = scope.people[index];
                   row.filename = filename;
                   scope.$apply();
               });
           }
       }
   });
   app.controller('merchantController',function($scope,$timeout) {
       $scope.people = [{"name": "sd", "place": "hyd1", filename: ''}, {"name": "sd", "place": "hyd2", filename: ''}, {"name": "sd", "place": "hyd3", filename: ''}, {"name": "sd", "place": "hyd4", filename: ''}, {"name": "sd", "place": "hyd5", filename: ''}, {"name": "sd", "place": "hyd6", filename: ''}];
       $scope.gridOptions = {
           data: 'people',
           columnDefs: [{
               field: 'name',
               cellTemplate: '<input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.name"/>'
           }, {
               field: 'place',
               cellTemplate: '<input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.place"/>'
           }, {
               displayName: 'Browse',
               cellTemplate: '<input type="file" file-upload name="img{{row.rowIndex}}" index="{{row.rowIndex}}" filename={{row.entity.filename}} />'
           }, {displayName: "Remove", cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="remove(row.rowIndex)">Remove</button>'}]
       };

       $scope.remove = function (ind) {
           var index = this.row.rowIndex;
           $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
           var form = document.forms.namedItem("gridform");
           form.elements["img" + index].value = "";
           $scope.people.splice(index, 1);
       };

   });

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working fine when I made a sample file, when I included in my project again the file in the next row is getting deleted